# SQL Count and Group by - Do count and group, used together, allow for this?

Tags: sql, count, group-by

i'm working on an exercise query, using standard SQL.
What I need, in this example, is get the Name and the ID of every student who has enrolled in any course more than 2 times. In this case, the tables have the following information (I'll list only the columns that matter for this exercise):

Student has the ID and the name of the student.
Course has the course ID.
Class has the group ID and the course ID.
Registration has the reg. ID, the student ID, the class ID and the grade obtained.

So, it all sums up to find out which students have more than 2 entries in Registration that are matched to the same course, via Class. So far I've gotten this:

```
   SELECT Student.id, Student.name FROM 
     Student S JOIN Registration R on S.id = R.studentID
        WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
            Course C JOIN Class L on L.courseId = C.id
                JOIN Registration R on R.classId = L.id
                    group by C.id ) > 2
```

The question is, do Count and Group by work this way?? Do they allow me to get the amount of matches on each group, or do they just give me the results on the set, as I fear they do?

If so, any ideas on how may I approach this problem??
Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start reading up on the **HAVING** clause.  Also, you aliases Student as S, so you need to use the prefix "S" for the SELECT clause, not "Student"

```
SELECT S.id StudentID, S.name, C.id CourseID
FROM Student S
JOIN Registration R on S.id = R.studentID
JOIN Class L on R.ClassId = L.id
JOIN Course C on L.courseId = C.id 
GROUP BY S.id, S.name, C.id
HAVING COUNT(R.studentID) > 2;
```

All 4 tables are joined to produce a resultset representing all students registrated for any class of a course. Then we `GROUP BY` the student-course combination, and find out the ones where there are more than 2 registrations using the `HAVING` clause.  Of course, if you meant "2 or more" instead of "more than 2", you'd use `> 1` or `>= 2` instead of `> 2`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, and for the advice on the Having clause. I fail to see how that query relates to what I need, but I'll try to work with Having to make one myself. Thanks!

Comment: Nice ^^ now I see what you meant. Thanks! It's pretty clear now!